# How to change the default port 5000 in Svelte?

Tags: port, svelte, svelte-3

I am not getting how to change the default `5000` port in Svelte to some other port if we install the sample template through degit.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `sveltejs/template` uses `sirv-cli`.
You can add `--port` or `-p` in your `start:dev` script in `package.json`.

Instead of:

```json
"start:dev": "sirv public --single --dev"
```

Use:

```json
"start:dev": "sirv public --single --dev --port 5555"
```

You can see more of `sirv-cli` options:

https://github.com/lukeed/sirv/tree/master/packages/sirv-cli

Answer (score 34):

You can use env vars `HOST` and `PORT`.

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/sirv-cli:

> Note: The HOST and PORT environment variables will override flag values.

Like this:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=6000 npm run dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `package.json`, you will find this line:

```json
"start": "sirv public --no-clear"
```

Change it to this, or to any other port that you want:

```json
"start": "sirv public --no-clear  --port 8089"
```

Answer (score 2):

As now svelte uses [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/) so for both `svelte` and `sveltekit`.

If you want to change it to  a fixed port for your project. Inside your `package.json` file under `"scripts":` change the `dev` script

```json
 "dev": "vite --port 3333",
```

If you want to change it at the time of starting development server

```bash
npm run dev -- --port=3333
```